# Java regex to find whitespaces or upper-case characters

Tags: java, regex, whitespace, casing

I have a method that validates a string and makes sure it doesn't have any whitespaces or upper-case characters:

```
boolean validate(String input) {
    if(input.matches(".*\\S.*([A-Z]+)")) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this, it simply doesn't work. It doesn't throw any exceptions, it just allows all input string ("HelloWorld", "hello world", "Hello world", etc.) to pass validation. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Your regex will match if your string has at least one **non-whitespace** character and then at least one capital letter. It will not perform the match that you want.

Comment: You had better use a "negative regex" and `.find()`; ie, `final Pattern wsOrUpper = Pattern.compile("[A-Z\\s]")`, and then try and `wsOrUpper.matcher(input).find())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.matches("[^A-Z\\s]+")`

It will return true if your string does not contain any upper case characters or white space characters.

**Explanation**

the bit between `[...]` is called a character class, it matches all characters provided

- `^` makes it negative, so it matches everything not provided
- `A-Z` is the range of upper case characters
- `\\s` is short hand for any white space character
- `+` ensures that your string is at least 1 character or more.

Comment: Why the caret at the begining? Also still too complex.

Comment: The `^` makes it a negative character class, so it means none of the characters in the [], i.e. no upper case letters, and not white space.

Comment: Yes, of course - silly me. That would work, though I still think my answer is simpler.

Comment: @Guss Why use `|` if you can combine all options in one character class?

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, regular expression to match white space or capital letters is:

```
.*[A-Z\s].*
```

If any single such character will invalidate the input, then this will work nicely.

Normally, I would drop the `.*` at the start and end, but Java's `String#matches()` must match the entire string or else it fails, unlike the popular `=~` operator in dynamic languages that will match any substring.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to,

```
boolean validate(String input) {
    if(input.matches(".*?[A-Z\\s].*")) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Because `matches` function tries to match the whole string, you don't need to go for anchors. The above code would return false if the input string contains spaces or uppercase letters.

Comment: no need for that. It would reduce some debugging steps.